# Why is "de" used instead of "du" in “les enfants de parents mariés”?

Tags: prépositions

Why is "de" used instead of "du" in the following sentence?

> Les enfants de parents mariés

Answer (score 4):

Your question would rather be whether to use "de" or "des". "Parents" being plural, "du" should be replaced by its plural "des".

Yet indeed, "de" and "du" have a very different meaning in this context.

Let's consider an example where both "de" and "du" would be grammatically correct:

> Les enfants du facteur
>   Les enfants de facteurs

In the first example, "du facteur" is definite, we are talking about the children of a postman in particular (for example the one we just met while walking outside).

In the second example, "de facteur" is indefinite: we are talking about children of postmen in general.

It's the same in your case, but while

> Les enfants de parents mariés

sound perfectly fine,

> Les enfants des parents mariés

sounds quite wrong, because "parents mariés" is not precise enough: we are expecting something more definite because of "des", like

> Les enfants des parents mariés du quartier

Comment: In "Les enfants de facteurs", facteurs should be plural because we are talking about postmen in general and not about a particular postman

Comment: @GhislainLeveque Yes, indeed. I missed this one. I'll correct it right away.

Answer (score 3):

*Les enfants du parents mariés* would be absolutely wrong since *du* means *de le* and *parents mariés* is a plural.

But you could ask yourself why not *des* instead of *de*. Both would be grammatically correct and would have a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It is short for:

> Les enfants nés de parents mariés

So, in this case, "de" stand for "from"

Comment: I wonder what your explanation would be if the sentence was “les parents de jumeaux”…

Answer (score 0):

Même si le sujet *de vs du* a déjà bien été expliqué, je me permets de faire une petite synthèse à ce sujet. On peut facilement savoir lequel utiliser en réfléchissant sur la quantité :

Si pas de quantité + nom masculin => **du**

> J'aimerais du lait, du pain, du soleil,...

Si pas de quantité + nom féminin => **de**

> J'aimerais de l'eau, de la salade, de la viande,...

Si une quantité est précisée => **de ou d'**

> J'aimerais une assiette de pâtes, un verre de lait, une carafe d'eau,...

Il y a aussi la préposition DE + article 'indéfini' :

On ne dira pas :

> Les enfants des parents mariés.
>   Les jeux des enfants.

Mais

> Les enfants de parents mariés.

car à chaque enfant correspond une paire de parents.

> Les jeux d'enfants.

car pour chaque jeu, il y a plusieurs enfants.

Ceci est une synthèse qui regroupe la majorité des cas. Il en existe probablement d'autres mais je pense qu'avec ceci, on peut se débrouiller facilement.

Comment: Les blocs “code” sont prévus pour y mettre du code, et sont marqués sémantiquement comme tel. Il faut donc éviter de les utiliser dans tout autre cas. Dans certaines situations, comme par exemple lorsque quelqu’un utilise un logiciel de synthèse vocale pour lire une page, cela peut poser problème.